# How to calculate (add) datetime values in MQL4?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

With MQL4 I have troubles in handling **`datetime`**.

What I want to do is put `datetime` in array by month or by year.

For now I do in this way.

```
datetime myDate;

myDate[0] = D'2010.01.01 00:00';
myDate[1] = D'2010.02.01 00:00';
myDate[2] = D'2010.03.01 00:00';
myDate[3] = D'2010.04.01 00:00';
.
.
```

However I want to do this like this below

```
myDate[0] = D'2010.01.01 00:00';
for (int i = 1;i < 6 ;i+=){
    myDate[i] = myDate[i - 1] + 1year;
}
```

in case of month,

```
myDate[0] = D'2010.01.01 00:00';
for (int i = 1; i < 12 ; i++){
    myDate[i] = myDate[i - 1] + 1month
}
```

**Q:** How do I calculate adding **`1month`** or **`1year`**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**MQL4** documentation declared **`datetime`** type to be internally represented as an amount of seconds since an agreed time-scale datum ( being **`1970-01-01 00:00`** ).

This said  <sup>( and polishing a bit the syntax compliance )</sup>
the code
may read

```
oneYear = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;   // yes, astronomers would kill me
                                // for not solving those seconds,
                                // that sum up until a leap year
                                // consumes 'em on Feb-29th day     :o)
```

another option
so as to manipulate
`datetime` in a bit more
comfortable manner, addressing
`datetime`'s natural component is hacky, but worth:
StringToTime

```
string TimeToString( datetime aDatetimeVALUE,
                     int aModeOfDISPLAY = TIME_DATE|TIME_MINUTES
                    )
```

> Converting a value containing time in seconds elapsed since 01.01.1970 into a `string` of `"yyyy.mm.dd hh:mi"` format.

Here, one can simply add +1 to proper position of this intermediate format ( without a need to handle all the derived and influenced values as present in the `struct MqlDateTime`, where **`day_of_week`** and **`day_of_year`** are definitely not my favourite ones to re-calculate once moving +1 month etc.

```
aCurrentYEAR  = int(  StringSubstr( aDatetimeSTRING, 0, 4 ) );
aCurrentMONTH = int(  StringSubstr( aDatetimeSTRING, 5, 2 ) );
aCurrentDAY   = int(  StringSubstr( aDatetimeSTRING, 8, 2 ) );

aNextYEAR     = aCurrentYEAR  + 1;
aNextMONTH    = aCurrentMONTH + 1;
```

Finally

```
StringFormat( "%04d.%02d.%02d 00:00", aYearNUMBER, aMonthNUMBER, aDayNUMBER )
```

will do the re-assembly for calling another MQL4 standard function:

**`datetime StringToTime( string aDatetimeSTRING )`**

> The function converts a string containing time or date in `"yyyy.mm.dd [hh:mi]"` format into **`datetime`** type.

Another approach may use a fully-decomposed **`datetime`** aritmetics by using

```
int aYE  = TimeYear(      aDatetimeVALUE );
int aMO  = TimeMonth(     aDatetimeVALUE );
int aDA  = TimeDay(       aDatetimeVALUE );
int aHO  = TimeHour(      aDatetimeVALUE );
int aMI  = TimeMinute(    aDatetimeVALUE );
int aDoW = TimeDayOfWeek( aDatetimeVALUE );
int aDoY = TimeDayOfYear( aDatetimeVALUE );

datetime aSameTimeNextYEAR = StructToTime( (MqlDateTime) { aYE + 1,
                                                           aMO,
                                                           aDA,
                                                           aHO,
                                                           aMI,
                                                           aDoW,
                                                           aDoY
                                                           }
                                           );
```

Comment: Thanks I understood. There is a no simple way to add 1month, however this work-around is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 4):

Using `MqlDateTime`,`TimeToStruct` and `StructToTime`structure like below:

```
MqlDateTime time;
TimeToStruct(TimeCurrent(),time);

time.year++;
time.mon++;
datetime newTime = StructToTime(time);
```

Comment: should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
int month = PeriodSeconds(PERIOD_MONTH);
```

for year - not sure that you can use some constant, but looks like 12 months is okay, another option is to use `MqlDateTime` assigning year and then converting to `datetime` using `StructToTime()`;

**UPDATE:** month is not a good approach as every month has different number of seconds

Comment: Daniel, the `PERIOD_MONTH` is an artificial FOREX-flow of time "framing" serving a **constant** amount of seconds - definitely not the way to go for the asked problem, as a natural flow of time in February, with **`{28|29}`-calendar days** has by definition a different amount of seconds than in January, with **`31`-calendar days**

Answer (score 0):

I attach a script illustrating the loop.

Essential logic:

1. add 31 days to the defined datetime
2. get the new month, ignoring the specific day
3. generate the new date as a string with the new month
4. convert the string into the new datetime
5. add 31 days to **this new datetime**
6. repeat from 2

---

```
    void OnStart(){

       datetime myDate[6];
       myDate[0] = D'2010.01.01 00:00';
       Print(TimeToStr(myDate[0]));

       datetime dTempDate = myDate[0];
       int iSecondsIn31Days = 24*60*60*31, iTempMonth = 0;

       for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
          iTempMonth = TimeMonth(dTempDate + iSecondsIn31Days); //add 31 days and get the month, we don't care whether the day is the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd, we just want the month
          myDate[i] = dTempDate = StrToTime(TimeYear(myDate[0]) +"." +iTempMonth +"." +TimeDay(myDate[0])); //format the string to datetime
          Print(TimeToStr(myDate[i])); //to verify
       }

    }
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Methods you need to use

MqlDateTime , StructToTime ,TimeToStruct

You can do your job in less steps using these

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had the same issue.

As it is internally stored in seconds, just add the proper ammount of seconds. It is as easy as that....

```
   datetime date_from = TimeCurrent();
   // this adds two days from now (60*60 = 1 Hour) * (24 hours = 1 Day) * (2 = two days)
   date_from += 60*60*24*2;
   
   Comment(date_from);
```